# how to discard a random number after it has been used?

Tags: python, random

I am programming a program to test my chemistry knowledge.
But I want once a random number appears, it won't appear a second time.
For example, when the number 1 appears (hydrogen), it will not appear twice.
How to do it?
---the programming language i am using is python---
My English is not good, so there is a grammar mistake, please forgive me
THANKS FOR THE HELP

```
from random import randint

computer = randint(1,20)
loop = True

if computer == 1:
    computer = 'Hidro'
if computer == 2:
    computer = 'Heli'
if computer == 3:
    computer = 'Liti'
if computer == 4:
    computer = 'Beri'
if computer == 5:
    computer = 'Bo'
if computer == 6:
    computer = 'Cacbon'
if computer == 7:
    computer = 'Nitơ'
if computer == 8:
    computer = 'Oxi'
if computer == 9:
    computer = 'Flo'
if computer == 10:
    computer = 'Neon'
if computer == 11:
    computer = 'Natri'
if computer == 12:
    computer = 'Magie'
if computer == 13:
    computer = 'Nhôm'
if computer == 14:
    computer = 'Silic'
if computer == 15:
    computer = 'Photpho'
if computer == 16:
    computer = 'Lưu Huỳnh'
if computer == 17:
    computer = 'Clo'
if computer == 18:
    computer = 'Agon'
if computer == 19:
    computer = 'Kali'
if computer == 20:
    computer = 'Canxi'

while loop:
    print('Nguyên tố:' + computer)
    choose = input('Nguyên Tử Khối:' )
    
    if computer == 'Hidro':
        if choose == '1':
            print('Đúng!')
        else:
            print('Học lại đi mày')
    if computer == 'Heli':
        if choose == '4':
            print('Đúng!')
        else:
            print('Học lại đi mày')
    if computer == 'Liti':
        if choose == '7':
            print('Đúng!')
        else:
            print('Học lại đi mày')
    if computer == 'Beri':
        if choose == '9':
            print('Đúng!')
        else:
            print('Học lại đi mày')
    if computer == 'Bo':
        if choose == '11':
            print('Đúng!')
        else:
            print('Học lại đi mày')
    if computer == 'Cacbon':
        if choose == '12':
            print('Đúng!')
        else:
            print('Học lại đi mày')
    if computer == 'Nitơ':
        if choose == '14':
            print('Đúng!')
        else:
            print('Học lại đi mày')
    if computer == 'Oxi':   
        if choose == '16':
            print('Đúng!')
        else:
            print('Học lại đi mày')
    if computer == 'Flo':   
        if choose == '19':
            print('Đúng!')
        else:
            print('Học lại đi mày')
    if computer == 'Neon':  
        if choose == '20':
            print('Đúng!')
        else:
            print('Học lại đi mày')
    if computer == 'Natri': 
        if choose == '23':
            print('Đúng!')
        else:
            print('Học lại đi mày')
    if computer == 'Magie': 
        if choose == '24':
            print('Đúng!')
        else:
            print('Học lại đi mày')
    if computer == 'Nhôm':  
        if choose == '27':
            print('Đúng!')
        else:
            print('Học lại đi mày')
    if computer == 'Silic': 
        if choose == '28':
            print('Đúng!')
        else:
            print('Học lại đi mày')
    if computer == 'Photpho':   
        if choose == '31':
            print('Đúng!')
        else:
            print('Học lại đi mày')
    if computer == 'Lưu Huỳnh': 
        if choose == '32':
            print('Đúng!')
        else:
            print('Học lại đi mày')
    if computer == 'Clo':   
        if choose == '35,5':
            print('Đúng!')
        else:
            print('Học lại đi mày')
    if computer == 'Agon':  
        if choose == '39,9':
            print('Đúng!')
        else:
            print('Học lại đi mày')
    if computer == 'Kali':  
        if choose == '39':
            print('Đúng!')
        else:
            print('Học lại đi mày')
    if computer == 'Canxi': 
        if choose == '40':
            print('Đúng!')
        else:
            print('Học lại đi mày')
    if choose == 'End':
        exit()
```

Comment: Note that you should really learn about `dict`s to avoid all this duplicated code.

Comment: yes it always repeats the same code

Comment: 1. Make a list of the elements you want to pick from.  2. Shuffle your list of elements.  3. Pick the elements from your shuffled list in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to:

1. Create a list of dictionaries;
2. Choose a random element from the list;
3. remove the element;
4. Repeat the process with a loop until the list is empty (using the len() function to determine the length of the list).

Here is a minimal example with three elements:

```
import random                                       

elements = [
        {"Hidro": 1},
        {"Heli": 2},
        {"Liti": 3}
        ]

while len(elements) > 0:
        selection = random.choice(elements)
        
        print(elements)
        print(selection)

        elements.remove(selection)
```

Output (yours is likely going to be different due to randomness):

```
[{'Hidro': 1}, {'Heli': 2}, {'Liti': 3}]
{'Liti': 3}
[{'Hidro': 1}, {'Heli': 2}]
{'Heli': 2}
[{'Hidro': 1}]
{'Hidro': 1}
```

You can tap into the list with *index notation* and you can select elements from dictionaries using *keywords*. For example, `elements[0]` would be `{'Hidro': 1}` (because `{'Hidro': 1}` is at index 0 of `elements`), and `elements[0]["Hidro"]` would be 1 (because 1 is the value for the key, `"Hidro"`). With this, you can eliminate much of the redundancy from your code.

As was pointed out in a comment, you need to familiarize yourself with lists and dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

To randomize the order in which the questions appear, you can generate a random list of unique integers in a range that will correspond to your question numbers.

First, create an empty list. Create a loop that generates a random number as long as the list length is less than your total number of questions. On each iteration, check if the random number is in the list. If it isn't append it to the list. Then, use these values to randomize your question numbers:

```py
randomOrder = [];
while len(randomOrder) < 20:
   randomNum = randint(1, 20)
   if randomNum not in randomOrder:
      randomOrder.append(randomNum)
```

You could then use a `dict` or `list` to store the questions and map them to the randomized question order.